# How to Create Desktop Shortcut Parameter When Deploying Blender 3.6.5 with MSI installer?

Tags: installation

I'm trying to deploy Blender 3.6.5 to a bunch of PCs, and wondered if there was a switch/parameter for the installer to create a desktop shortcut.

I've tried `CREATESHORTCUT=1` and `DESKTOPSHORTCUT=1` but neither of these have worked.

Comment: Under Windows I always have to delete the desktop shortcut that is created automatically when you install Blender. I wish there was an option to **prevent** it being created!

Comment: You are probably better off downloading the zipped package and scripting the installation process and creating the shortcut